# JBPM 7: How to get login user information

Tags: jboss, jbpm

I would like to get login user (username, roles ...) when start new process via KieSession.

Any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserGroupCallback` is the kie API entrypoint that it is responsible for verifying whether a user or group exists and for collecting groups for a specific user.

Notice that default `UserGroupCallback` is based on the security context, therefore it can only retrieve information about authenticated user.

You can see different custom implementations here:
https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/tree/master/jbpm-human-task/jbpm-human-task-core/src/main/java/org/jbpm/services/task/identity

And this is the property for configuring a custom one: `org.jbpm.ht.custom.callback`